# Extract text from image using Pytesser

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, pytesser

I have installed Pytesser to extract text from image

```
     from PIL import Image
     from pytesser import *
     print image_to_string
```

the above commands are working
but when i type the code

```
           from pytesser import *
           from PIL import Image
           image = Image.open('C:/Users/Anmol/Desktop/PYTHON/text_image.jpg')
          image_to_string(image)
```

I get the error:

**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Anmol\Desktop\PYTHON\text_image.py", line 23, in 
>       image_to_string(image)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 31, in
>   image_to_string
>       call_tesseract(scratch_image_name, scratch_text_name_root)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesser.py", line 21, in
>   call_tesseract
>       proc = subprocess.Popen(args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Plzz guide me what to do as I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) for windows.